# конвертация .htaccess в nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

есть два файла .htaccess

в корне /

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

в папке public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

использовал онлайн конверторы в итоге получился такой конфиг:

```
server {  
listen 80;
server_name site.com;
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
# home directory
root /opt/WWWRoot/buzz;
client_max_body_size 100m;  
charset utf-8;

location / {

index index.php index.html;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /public/$1 last;
}

location /public {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css|txt|zip|ico|gz|csv|ico)$ {
access_log off;
expires 10d;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
try_files $uri =404;
# for PHP-FPM over socket
fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/buzz.sock; 
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include       fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

}

}
```

При заходе на site.com видно что правила не отробатывают и не отоброжаться папки лежащие в /public

и редирект уходит в цикл 
    /public/public/public/public

Помогите правильно сконвертировать тк уже 2 дня бьюсь ;(

Comment: Что-то я могу понять что тут произсходил. `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1` кажется перепишет **всё** в `/index.php`

Comment: О, я понял, это правило никогда не работает в `.htaccess`, потому что файлы не могу начинаться со слеша

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}
```

И

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
}
```

Comment: непомогло результат тотже